# S3 standby/resume in PCLinuxOS on a desktop PC?

Tags: standby, acpi, pclinuxos

I've just installed PCLinuxOS on a regular desktop PC. It's working fine except for S3 standby/resume (I'm not interested in S4 hibernate).

**What packages do I need to install, and what settings to I need to set, in order to get S3 standby/resume to work?**

I'm a Windows geek but just starting with Linux now, so please don't assume too much.

Do you need to know some hardware specs?
The hardware is pretty much a regular PC, nothing fancy and fairly recent. Core 2 Duo, Intel chipset, Nvidia 8400 GS, SATA disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is given [in the PCLinusOS forum](http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php/topic,65049.msg527318.html#msg527318).